# OkHttp3 java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:6000 in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, okhttp

I was facing the below shown error from OkHttp3 in Jenkins Pipeline. I tried the few ways that other post suggest but there is no luck. I was not facing this issue when working locally but only in Jenkins.

I was actually doing integration testing. So the server will be the containers from `docker-compose.yml` file.

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

Error:

```
<java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on http://localhost:6000/...>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Client Builder:

```
List<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<Protocol>();
protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .protocols(protocols)
        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .build();
```

Request Builder:

```
String baseUrl = "http://localhost:6000/sender";
Request request = new Request.Builder()
         .url(baseUrl)
         .headers(headers)
         .header("accept", "application/json")
         .header("Connection", "close")
         .header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
         .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
         .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), payLoad))
         .build();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
return call.execute();
```

OkHttp3 version: `3.14.9`